# Annotating a const member function with pure attribute

Tags: c++, gcc

The gcc documentation for [`__attribute__((pure))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bpure_007d-function-attribute-3348) states:

> Many functions have no effects except the return value and their return value depends only on the parameters and/or global variables. Such a function can be subject to common subexpression elimination and loop optimization just as an arithmetic operator would be. These functions should be declared with the attribute `pure`.

What does it mean to only depend on the parameters? Consider:

```
struct Wrapper {
    int i;

    int get() const { return i; }
    void set(int x) { i = x; }
};
```

Is it valid to label `Wrapper::get()` as a `pure` member function? It only depends on the implicit `Wrapper` instance, but that data could change.

Comment: This paper may be relevant http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0078r0.pdf

Comment: The implicit object (this) parameter is still a parameter. Syntax is inconsequential. Call if foo(x) or x.foo() or whatever.

Comment: @Danh It's not totally clear from the paper what the answer to this question is. It seems somewhat noncommittal.

Comment: Note GCC 9 has put some more restrictive descriptions in the relevant sections of its manual. This still does not guarantee the semantics among different implementations, see https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=43275 for example.

Answer (score 6):

> Is it valid to label `Wrapper::get()` as a `pure` member function? It only depends on the implicit `Wrapper` instance, but that data could change.

Yes, `Wrapper::get()` meets the requirements of gcc's `pure` attribute. Note, however, that `__attribute__((pure))` doesn't mean *pure in the academic sense*, i.e. possessing the property of referential transparency. The latter can be communicated through a stricter [`__attribute__((const))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bconst_007d-function-attribute-3303):

> `__attribute__((const))`
>
> Many functions do not examine any values except their arguments, and
>   have no effects except the return value. Basically this is just
>   slightly more strict class than the `pure` attribute below, since
>   function is not allowed to read global memory.
>
> Note that a function that has pointer arguments and examines the data
>   pointed to must *not* be declared `const`. Likewise, a function that calls
>   a non-`const` function usually must not be `const`. It does not make sense
>   for a `const` function to return `void`.

But since `Wrapper::get()` doesn't possess the property of referential transparency implied by `__attribute__((const))`, it cannot be labeled as such.

**EDIT**

The guarantee about the `pure`-ness (in gcc's sense) of a function can be used for optimizing only a block of code that doesn't contain writes to global memory (and, in particular, is not interspersed by calls to non-`pure` functions). Examples:

```
struct Wrapper {
    int i;

    int get() const __attribute__((pure)) { return i; }
    void set(int x) { i = x; }
};

long foo(Wrapper* w)
{
    // w->get() can be computed once
    return 2 * w->get() * w->get();
}

long bar(Wrapper* w)
{
    // w->get() can be computed once (even though below code writes to memory,
    // that memory is freshly allocated and cannot be accessed by w->get())
    long result = 2;
    result *= w->get();
    result *= w->get();
    return result;
}

long baz(Wrapper* w)
{
    // both w->get()s must be evaluated, since non-pure code occurs between them
    long result = 2;
    result *= w->get();
    std::cout << "Result after the first muliplication: " << result << std::endl;
    result *= w->get();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You sure about `__attribute__((const))`? Isn't implicit `this` a pointer argument to the function?

Comment: I'm not sure adding the term "referential transparency" helps. Does that term even have a definite meaning? Is `strlen()` not referentially transparent?

Comment: @Barry Generally speaking `strlen()` is not referentially transparent. It can be considered to be referentially transparent, when its argument points to immutable memory.

Comment: This answer is mostly correct, except the meanings of some terms in the academic sense. In fact, _referential transparency_  has quite many different meanings in different contexts, see [Referential transparency, definiteness and unfoldability](http://www.itu.dk/people/sestoft/papers/SondergaardSestoft1990.pdf). OTOH, "pure" is far more clearer in the sense of "side-effects free". However, it is still not enough clear for C++ which defines as-if rules to exclude equivalent non-volatile read operations but no control effects as side effects contributing to the observable behavior.